# Samba file system

Tags: permissions

I'm having trouble with the Samba file system. I started transferring around 7TB of data to another server through network sharing and I keep getting files cant be transferred permissions denied and I don't know what to do because I have to back up computers on our system.

Comment: Please edit your question to show specifically what you tried to do and specifically what didn't work. Include exact text of all error messages.

Comment: On the server, use `testparm` to see it's configuration. And `stat /path/to/shared_folder` to see that folder's permissions. On the client, check that you can actually read the files you want to transfer, and show us how the server is mounted on the client: `mount | grep "/your/mountpoint"`.